# Retry feign client properites

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I need to retry feign call for certain http status code and after 3 second for maximum 4 time.

Is there any properties that i can define on my application.yml or i need to write my custom Retryer that implement Retry interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feign has a build in [`Retryer`](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/d42fcef2bc9f470668e806f9215a09d7ddef0a5a/core/src/main/java/feign/Retryer.java) however you can not configure the `Retryer` via `application.yml`. <strike>I guess the Spring Boot Team assumed that people would use the deprecated Hystrix project for this matter.</strike>

Instead of configuring Feign by config you could write a bit of code:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/reference/html/index.html#creating-feign-clients-manually

In addition you have to map the corresponding status code to `RetryableException` using a custom `ErrorDecoder`.

```
public class CustomErrorDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {
  private final ErrorDecoder errorDecoder = new Default();

  @Override
  public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
    Exception exception = defaultErrorDecoder.decode(s, response);

    if(exception instanceof RetryableException){
      return exception;
    }

    if(response.status() == 499){
      return new RetryableException("499 blub", response.request().httpMethod(), null );
    }
    return exception;
  }
}
```

```
public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyApi myApi = Feign.builder()
                 .errorDecoder(new CustomErrorDecoder())
                 .target(MyApi.class, "https://api.hostname.com");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But there is some confustion when i call
Retryer.Default(period, maxPeriod, maxAttempts) what is the difference bw period and maxPeriod

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/d42fcef2bc9f470668e806f9215a09d7ddef0a5a/core/src/main/java/feign/Retryer.java#L55 The `period` is increased for every try by 1.5x until the `maxPeriod` is reached, therefore the period is capped at `maxPeriod`.

Comment: What if i want to define period, maxPeriod and maxAttempts in my application.yml? is there any specific properties for this which feign supports?

Comment: You could add a custom config object for this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties

Comment: Thanks All clear now.

Comment: the above code working but when feign throw exception of "loadbalancer does not have available server" it is not throwing to error decoder class

Answer (score -1):

You can use retryable annotation.

Ex: You can throw custom exception when http status code is equal to 404

```
@Service
public interface MyService {

    @Retryable(value = CustomException.class, maxAttempts = 2, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 100))
    void retry(String str) throws CustomException;
}
```

Comment: How would the REST-resource raise the CustomException over http?

Comment: You write error decoder